# Using Windows RDP Protocol to connect to OS X

Tags: windows, mac, remote-desktop

Are there any programs that enable me to connect to my Mac (OS X Mavericks) using Windows RDP (so that I can use the RDP programs that comes with most Windows versions)?

I am aware of the program `xrdp` which I run on linux to allow me to connect to my linux computers through the Windows RDP Protocol, is there something similar for Mac?

Comment: This site http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1770325 perfectly answered my question. :)